# Index fields not supported error while migrating MongoDB data (AWS Instance) to Azure CosmoDB

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to migrate my data from **MongoDB 4.0.6 running on one ec2 instance (AWS)** to **Azure CosmoDB (MongoDB 4.0)** by using **mongodump** and **mongorestore** commands. But I am returned with an error:

- Failed: <database.collection>: error creating indexes for <database.collection>: createIndex error: 2dsphereIndexVersion.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

ref: https://osamaoracle.com/2020/05/23/migrating-from-mongodb-to-azure-cosmo-db-using-mongorestore-and-mongodump-manually-offline/ (I have followed this guide to migrate my data from MongoDB to CosmoDB)